# "Copy" a php-file and include the POST-variable

Tags: php

I work on a PHP-app with some live functions etc. I have created a PHP script that does the following:

- Based on a form input, it creates a folder with the input name, eg. JOHN. (called $dir)
- It then creates a MySQL database table with the name the prefix_JOHN.
- It then copies and moves the system templates files to the JOHN-folder.

Then my problem is - I need script to create two files with a specific content - but the variable called from the form input must be included so it calls from the specific (here) JOHN-table in the database.

I tried just to copy - but it requires to manually edit the file. As there'll be unlimited tables created, I don't want to do this. :)

I then tried to make the script create a new file. Worked - except it can't include PHP-variables or tags - which makes sense, of course, but I am stuck now. :(

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nanne's answer is the way to go. But if you really curious about this, of course you can write the code to edit the script.

1. Copy the master PHP file to user specific PHP file
2. Get the contents of the newly created file
3. Replace all variables with `str_replace`. Maybe something like this:

   `$contents = str_replace('$name = "NAME"', '$name = "John"', $contents)`
4. Save the contents back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

- save all the instance-specific data to a central database.
- Have all your instances query that database for their specific variables like databasename, root folder etc

Comment: I see that might be the only solution. But is there no way to create a PHP-file and edit it with the variables? :)

Comment: Well sure, you might hack all sorts of things. You can just call some commandline stuff that creates your desired result, you can put the code in a string that you edit, and then use fwrite ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php ) to save it in a file, and there could be many other options, but I think this is the cleanest way.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) However, I'll let the thread stay open for a little while longer to see if there's any other answers.